# Namespace gets overwritten using rollup generated files

Tags: bundler, rollup, rollupjs

- Rollup Version: 0.66.6
- Operating System (or Browser): Mac, Chrome
- Node Version: 10.13.0

  1. Generate script using rollup with this configuration

```
const outputFileNamespace = "Foo";

const baseObject = {
    input: 'js/modules/',
    output: {
        name: outputFileNamespace,
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true,
        banner: "/*Copyright text*/"
    },
    plugins: [(environment === PROD_ENV) && uglify()]
};
```

2. Generate multiple files using this configuration : js1.js , js2.js
3. Load these files in browser, namespace gets overriden

#### Expected Behavior

If we need to generate multiple output files with the common global namespace as "Foo" here, there should be some check in the generated file which checks for the existence of a global namespace

#### Actual Behavior

Namespace gets overwritten and the latter one js functions are available

Answer (score 0):

Use a dot separated namespace for each build such as `app.foo` or use the option `output.extend` for extending instead of replacing the given namespace.